# onChange is appending data multiple times when checking for a string character

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to append a drop down value to a textarea field, it works as a mention. So if there is an "@" call the dropdown and user will select a user, once selected the dropdown show hide it self, and the user should be able to append their comment data.

> the issue im having is that `setCommentBody` is appending the selectedUser **multiple times/ on every comment change** in the
> textarea

My objective is

1. check for @ symbol (which its already doing)
2. render drop down once @ symbol is called( which is already doing)
3. once a value is selected hide drop down and add their comment (dropdown hides only if @ symbol is removed, which it should hide after a value is selected)

The mention should pretty much work exactly how stackoverflow comment section has it.

this is what i have so far

```
const [comment_body, setCommentBody] = useState("");
const [mentionedUser, setMentionedUser] = useState(false);

const commentChange = (comment) => {
  console.log("this is the selected User", selectedUser); // selected user is a reducer initalState
  // call this condition if @ is mentioned once
  if (comment.includes("@")) {
    setMentionedUser(true); // render dropwdown
    setCommentBody(comment.concat(selectedUser)); // append the selected user like @barnowl with the respective comment data
  } else {
    console.log("can you see me");
    setMentionedUser(false); // hide dropdown
    setCommentBody(comment);
  }

  setGifUrl(""); // irrelvant to the problem ignore
};
```

**PostItemContainer**

```
<CommentForm
  commentChange={(e: any) => commentChange(e.target.value)}
  comment_body={comment_body}
  onSubmit={(e) => commentSubmit(e, post.id)}
  gifUrl={selectGif}
  isGif={gifUrl}
  mentionedUser={mentionedUser}
/>;
```

**CommentForm (snippet)**

```
 .... 
 <OurTextField
  type="gif-commentfield"
  selectedUser={selectedUser}
  comment_body={props.comment_body}
  commentChange={props.commentChange}
  setGifSelected={() => setGifSelected(true)}
/>;
 {
  props.mentionedUser && (
    <select
      value={selectedUser}
      onChange={(e) => setSelectedOptionValue(e.target.value)}
      name="mentionedUsers"
    >
      {mentionUsers.map((item, key) => (
        <option key={key} value={item.display}>
          {item.display}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

A minimal working example of my issue

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-ives-lfckq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: in your code sandbox, I don't see the username getting appended to the comment

Comment: sorry for the delay, you have to press space or another character and the username will populate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the use case correctly, the name insertion logic should be triggered when the selection field is changed:

```
const commentChange = (comment) => {
  setCommentBody(comment);
  if (comment.includes("@")) {
    showMentionList(true);
  }
};
const selectedUserChange = (user) => {
  setSelectedUser(user);
  setCommentBody(commentBody.concat(user).replace("@", ""));
  showMentionList(false);
};

...

<select
  value={selectedUser}
  onChange={(e) => selectedUserChange(e.target.value)}
  name="mentionedUsers"
>
  {users.map((item, key) => (
    <option key={key} value={item}>
      {item}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>
```

Does this work for you? See: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-haze-qwb41?file=/src/App.js

Comment: is there anyway we can keep the at symbol before the username while keeping the same logic in tact. Sorta like a discord mention or twitter mention.

Comment: You can keep the `@` and replace `if (comment.includes("@"))` with a more elaborated logic. For example, you could track the exact changes to determine at which position the user is writing and if the word the user is currently typing has a @ symbol at the beginning.

Comment: yeah i sorta did `comment.charAt(0).includes("@")` something along those lines, thanks.